# Using CSS to Overlap Text on Image -- Works on Screen, but not in Print

Tags: html, css, printing, media-queries, screen

I'll start by saying I'm not an HTML developer, but I very occasionally have to try to create something. Hopefully the answer to this is easier than I think.

I have used CSS to create a text box which overlaps an image. This displays exactly as desired on screen, but when I attempt to print the screen, it pops the text divs out and prints them in-line instead. I played around with @screen and @media but I just can't quite seem to crack this.

Here's an example of what I am seeing right now:

[image: Example of text displaying differently on screen versus print preview]

Here's the code I am using:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            @media screen {
                .learner-name {  
                    position: absolute;
                    color: black;
                    white-space: nowrap;
                    font-size: 10px;
                    width: 250px;
                    text-align: left;
                    top: 91px;
                    left: 168px;
                    width: 250px;
                    height: 20px;
                    }

                .date-completed {  
                    position: absolute;  
                    color: black;  
                    white-space: nowrap;  
                    font-size: 10px;  width: 250px;  
                    text-align: left;  
                    top: 111px;  
                    left: 168px;  
                    width: 250px;  
                    height: 20px;
                    }

                .container { 
                    position: relative; 
                    width:350px;
                    }
                } 
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <img style="width: 350px;" src="https://adtsb.sabacloud.com/production/NA6T1SNB099/CertificateTemplates/crttp000000000002520/local000000000000001/images/cert-side-1.PNG?v=546268" alt="Side 1" />
            <div class="learner-name">@@person.first_name@@&#160;@@person.last_name@@</div>
            <div class="date-completed">@@offering.date_marked_complete@@</div>
            <img style="width: 350px;" src="https://adtsb.sabacloud.com/production/NA6T1SNB099/CertificateTemplates/crttp000000000002520/local000000000000001/images/cert-side-2.PNG?v=248336" alt="Side 2" />
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You HTML is likely getting turned back into inline elements when the print preview gets generated. Is it essential that you print it straight from the browser? Could screen grab or save the page as an image and print it through adobe reader or something similar?

Comment: @paul-schultz that would work fine for me, but this is being rolled out to potentially hundreds to thousands of people, so asking them to do that is impractical. But I was tempted, believe me.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using print within your media query to style a printed version of your page. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@media#Description

`@media screen, print {`

Comment: Thank you for this -- I am aware of the @media print option, but cannot figure out how to get it to render correctly. All attempts to set the absolute position of the elements seem to be ignored when I print. Do you have any specific experience overlapping items  for print in this way?